# Avoiding IF in a simple mapping function

Tags: c++, ruby, r, function

I'm trying to avoid an IF in the following mapping function:

```
 X  Y
 1  11
 2  10
 3  9
 4  8
 5  7
 6  6
 7  5
 8  4
 9  3
10  2
11  1
12  12
```

It's basically `Y = (12 - X)`, except when `X = 12`. In this case, `Y = 12`.

The `Y` vector is the reverse of the `X` vector shifted by one position. Is there a way to write this function using `min` and `max` or something like this in order to avoid a conditional?

- I'm not attached to any programming language here

Comment: `Y = (X == 12) ? 12 : (12 - X);`

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke any rules. Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 8):

```
y = 12 - x%12;
```

works for all `x` from 1 to 12 inclusive. `%` is the C-style modulus operator, giving the remainder from dividing `x` by 12. That's zero if `x` is 12, and `x` for 1 to 11.

Comment: In `R` it would be `Y <- 12 - X%%12`

Answer (score 6):

Ruby answer:

```
x = (1..12).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

y = x.map{|n| 12 - n % 12}
#=> [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12]
```

This can be extended to work for any length by using `n.max` instead of `12`.